# How to convert a string to a Python array?

Tags: python

I have a string looks like this:

```
"[3 3 3 3 4 3 4 ...]"
```

And I need to convert this to a `python` array. Should I add `,` after every number before doing anything? or

Is this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the .split() function. Simply do:

```py
string = "..." # The string here
numbers = string[1:-1].split() # We have the 1:-1 here because we want to get rid of the square brackets that are in the string.
```

Comment: Does variable `number` is a `python` array now?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
dd = "[3 3 3 3 4 3 4]"
new_dd = dd.replace('[','').replace(']','').split(' ')
# ['3', '3', '3', '3', '4', '3', '4']
# if you want to convert int.

[int(d) for d in new_dd]
# [3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

But if you want a list of integers (int) rather than an array of strings, then you need:

```
s = "[3 3 4 3 4]"

numbers = s[1:-1].split() # a list of strings
print(numbers)
numbers = [int(n) for n in numbers] # a list of integers
print(numbers)
```

Prints:

```
['3', '3', '4', '3', '4']
[3, 3, 4, 3, 4]
```